# Windows OneNote file: Issues migrating to a Mac

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I have created some OneNote files in my windows 11 computer, and now I want to open them on a Mac. I am following this and several online resources.

But I am not able to achieve much here. I first need to upload my OneNote files. So I open file in OneNote app on my windows computer, and go to 'File', and click on 'Export' in left panel:

[image]

I can see a 'Export' button. But as soon as I click 'Export' button, it just go back to my opened file in the app, and nothing really happens.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this too.  I tried a few different paths and failed.  I will skip describing those attempts.  The following is a bit cumbersome, but it worked for me using Microsoft OneDrive at work.

There was a new notebook created on Mac that "My Notebook @ " referred to hereafter as the shared notebook.  I found that and opened it on Windows.  Now on both Windows and Mac I have the same notebook open.  You may want to make a change and sync both to see if you have everything set up correctly.  Again on Windows, moved all of the sections one by one from the old notebook to the shared notebook using the built-in OneNote move section functionality.  You may have to force sync on both sides before you will see all the sections.